# Why is this json file generating a URI is malformed error?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-cognitive-search

I'm trying to use azure pipelines to deploy an instance of cognitive search including a skillset via the pipeline. When trying to deploy the skillset using pipelines and JSON templates, i'm getting the error "URI is malformed".

The current JSON code looks like this:

```
{
        "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Custom.WebApiSkill",
        "name": "#3 - TEST",
        "description": "Extracts group and user permissions for a particular document from Sharepoint site.",
        "context": "/document",
        "uri": "https://{{FUNCTIONAPPNAME}}.azurewebsites.net/api/km-identify-customfields?code={{FUNCTIONHOSTKEY}}",
        "httpMethod": "POST",
        "timeout": "PT30S",
        "batchSize": 1,
        "degreeOfParallelism": null,
        "inputs": [
          {
            "name": "metadata_spo_item_path",
            "source": "/document/metadata_spo_item_path" 
          }
        ],
        "outputs": [
          {
            "name": "sp_groups_permissions",
            "targetName": "sp_groups_permissions"
          },
          {
            "name": "sp_users_permissions",
            "targetName": "sp_users_permissions"
          }
```

and because the pipeline is set up using runtime parameters to use one of two deployments for the indexer portion, I can be certain this code works just fine when attached to the index JSON for a sharepoint deployment. However, when I attach it to a blob based deployment I get the error:

```
{"error":{"code":"","message":"One or more skills are invalid. Details: Error in skill '#3 - TEST': 'uri' parameter is not well-formed"}}
```

Which then causes an indexer fail because it refers to a a skillset that doesn't exist.

The parameters for FUNCTIONAPPNAME are being given to it from the deployment pipeline:

```
trigger: none

parameters:
  - name: cognitiveSearchKey
    type: string

  - name: cognitiveSearchName
    type: string

  - name: tenantId
    type: string

  - name: repoCheckout
    type: string

  - name: storageConnectionString
    type: string

  - name: cognitiveAccountKey
    type: string

  - name: functionAppName
    type: string

  - name: resourceGroup
    type: string

  - name: azureServiceConnection
    type: string

pool:
  vmImage: "ubuntu-latest"

stages:
- stage: buildanddeploy
  displayName: Build and Deploy Congitive Search Functions
  jobs:
  - template: ./templates/deployCogSearch.yml
    parameters: 
      cognitiveSearchKey: ${{parameters.cognitiveSearchKey}}
      cognitiveSearchName: ${{parameters.cognitiveSearchName}}
      appId: "<appID>"
      appSecret: "<appsecret>"
      tenantId: ${{parameters.tenantId}}
      cognitiveAccountKey: ${{parameters.cognitiveAccountKey}}
      storageConnectionString: ${{parameters.storageConnectionString}}
      container: km3-test
      folder: km3
      functionAppName: ${{parameters.functionAppName}}
      resourceGroup: ${{parameters.resourceGroup}}
      azureServiceConnection: ${{parameters.azureServiceConnection}}
      repoCheckout: self
```

And that in turn is put into the code by the overarching pipeline that runs all the sub-pipelines and a bicep. The fact it's running just fine on another deployment suggests to me that I'm missing something simple, I just can't quite work out what!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you debug the variables passed and double check if there are special characters that need to be escaped , you can use a powershell task like this to check for variables passed:

```
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      echo 'Debugging information:'
      echo "FUNCTIONHOSTKEYvalue: $FUNCTIONHOSTKEY"
```

Comment: I've tried checking the variables, but what doesn't make a huge amount of sense is it's using the same variables the other working version of the deployment uses for everything apart from the data source.

Comment: FUNCTIONAPPNAME is this a prefix? did you try printing the variables? I am afraid it will be difficult to help you debug without more context.

Comment: FUNCTIONAPPNAME is a variable that gets replaced when the pipeline runs by a skill in another part of it. It's slightly difficult to give full context because its a pipeline thats one of 5 being deployed by one greater pipeline so several layers deep